# c++ counting jumps range at end

Tags: c++

What is going on here?

The header file:

```
// .h file
public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    static const size_type CAPACITY = 3;
private:
    value_type data[CAPACITY];
    size_type cursor;
```

The implementation file:

```
// .cpp file
for (cursor = 0; cursor <= CAPACITY; ++cursor)
{
    data[cursor] = -1;
    std::cout << "cursorPos: " << cursor << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
cursorPos: 0
cursorPos: 1
cursorPos: 2
cursorPos: 3220176896
```

Comment: Change "cursor <= CAPACITY" to "cursor < CAPACITY"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing `data` out of bounds. It has size `3`, so valid indices are in the range [0,2]. You are accessing the range [0,3].

Accessing an array out of bounds is *undefined behaviour*. You are writing to whatever happens to be in memory after the end of the array. In this case, it seems to affect the value of your index. But you can't even rely on this behaviour being reproducible.

This would be an idiomatic way of setting the elements of an array with a certain value:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::fill
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end, C++11 only

std::fill(std::begin(data), std::end(data), -1); // C++11
std::fill(data, data + CAPACITY, -1);            // C++03
```

Comment: But I'm printing the cursor. What does the out of bounds have to do with my cursor value? I.e., I expect cursor to be no greater than CAPACITY which = 3.

Comment: @TechMedicNYC Undefined behaviour. You are writing somewhere you shouldn't. All bets are off.

Comment: Strange world this c++. LOL If I write for x = do something; y = 3. I don't expect y to change x. Very odd. But I changed the loop to not exceed the array length and I get the expected cursor value.

Comment: Exactly. As someone already pointed out, the problem is that your for-loop is `cursor <= capacity` and it needs to be `cursor < capacity`.

Comment: It won't always change x. In fact, you're pretty lucky it didn't just segfault, which is usually what happens when you go outside array bounds.

Comment: @TechMedicNYC you asked the computer to do something nonsensical (use the 4th element of a 3-element array). You shouldn't be surprised when it comes back with nonsense.

Comment: @aruisdante sometimes a segfault is your friend... it let's you know the program did something wrong, `unlucky` is when it does something undefined, the compiler doesn't warn you (sometimes it knows, but not always), doesn't segfault, gives the wrong answer, and you don't notice.

Comment: Mm, I agree completely, lucky was a poor choice of words. I should have said `it was pure luck`

Comment: Thanks everyone. Thanks @juanchopanza, especially for the alternative code samples.